# Как сделать прозрачным дочерний элемент непрозрачного элемента?

Tags: html, css

```css
div.layer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
}

div.layer > div {
  top: 156px;
  left: 248px;
  width: 345px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<div class="layer">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Как вы можете видеть контейнер растянут на всю страницу и он немного прозрачно-черный. Необходимо добиться того, чтобы дочерний элемент был полностью прозрачным вне зависимости от того, какого цвета div.layer.

Сейчас все выглядит примерно так:
[image: Так выглядит сейчас]

То есть цвет дочернего элемента считается от цвета родителя => сделать его полностью прозрачным невозможно. Как решить эту задачу?

Использовать JavaScript допустимо. Но вот рисовать темные полоски слева, справа, снизу и сверху, чтобы посреди остался "незакрашенный" кусочек - нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40809/discussion-on-question-by-smellyshovel------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такой вариант

```css
div.layer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

div.layer div {
  top: 156px;
  left: 248px;
  width: 345px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1024px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>
дывоаыщшваоasdaskdhaisudhaidufhsidufhsidjfsdufhsidfusdifuhsdfuhsdifsdfsdfsdfdhfgh<br>

<div class="layer">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему курсор пропадает :D

Comment: Нет, такое решение не подходит. Тут даже самого затемнения нет.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, элемент перекрывает курсор. Если нужно выделение текста, придётся делать вокруг области 4 объекта с затемнением

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, добавил вариант с возможностью выделения текста, но тогда и в тёмном фоне можно будет выделять его

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, курсор не пропадает, просто цвет такой, что его инвертирование даёт его же.

Comment: @Doofy пропустил ответ без выделения текста (оно мне не нужно), можете убрать?

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, не понял, что нужно убрать?

Comment: А вот и нет, стоп. Это не решение. Добавил 2 кнопки внутрь дырки - они не нажимаются.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов `z-index: -1;` уберите и будут

Comment: @МатвейМамонов, скорее всего текст перекрывает кнопку

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев о, точно. Спасибо. Теперь и выделения нет. Ну что ж, тогда это верный ответ, я думаю.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев кстати, насчет моего решения. До ума я его не довел, потому что там нужна магия JS'а. Короче говоря я хотел сдвигать прозрачный div рамками (border), чтобы рамка, увеличиваясь, толкала дырку.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так из того примера что в комменте

http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/pbJRWK

```
body .loader_overlay {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background: transparent;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67), 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) inset;
        border-radius: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

Возможно ты ищешь что то такое http://codepen.io/hugo/pen/jFzqm

http://codepen.io/dani3lsz/pen/NNYvRM

Comment: вариант не работает, я добавил текст внутрь, его нельзя выделять

Comment: сделай ещё один див внутри

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете генерировать "дырку" при помощи инсертного box-shadow?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich я же сказал, я уже пробовал, не работает твой вариант

Comment: посмотри по ссылке я обновил

Comment: не работает в ie , как обычно greyscle ваш не кроссбраузерный

Comment: @LenovoID что такое ie?

Comment: Serge Esmanovich ie это internet explorer

Comment: @LenovoID так это старое что то сейчас же Edge у мелкомягких

Comment: Serge Esmanovich   я о нём и говорю , на нём и проверил и не работает

Comment: @LenovoID у меня такого нет не знаю как проверить, нужно винду ставить наверное, блин и знакомых с виндой нет

Comment: у меня linux , а виндоус 10 на virtualbox , но у супруги комп на windows и иногда я просто смотрю и при чём сразу в IE или EDGE и не работает в этих броузерах , в Лине не рабоает это в Midory , в стандартном броузере андроида, и если не работает в этих броузерах то в яблоках даже не смотрю